# InefficientFilter error on Microsoft Graph requests which were previously working

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api

Making the following request to the MS Graph to retrieve flagged messages ordered by due date:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$filter=flag/flagStatus%20eq%20%27flagged%27&$orderby=flag/dueDateTime/dateTime%20desc&$top=100`

would previously succeed and give back the expected results. Recently some users have been getting the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InefficientFilter",
    "message": "The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "5ef714c9-39a0-4167-a4d0-3682dcb46de4",
      "date": "2016-11-17T16:41:16"
    }
  }
}
```

Has a bug been introduced into the graph?

It is strange that this request was previously fine, and is now seen as inefficient. It also only happens on some users' accounts.

The same issue has also occurred with the following request to retrieve email attachments ordered by received date:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=hasAttachments%20eq%20true&$orderby=receivedDateTime%20desc&$expand=attachments($select=name,contentType,size,lastModifiedDateTime)&$top=6`

which now gets the same InefficientFilter error response. Note, the second request is to the v1.0 API so this is not limited to beta.

Also note that removing the orderby clause on the affected accounts will cause the requests to succeed.

Comment: This issue is happening to us as well, and is causing complete outage to all our users. Can someone at Microsoft please look at this ASAP?

Comment: Hehehe good luck to us developers that rely on microsoft having stable functionality. $orderby is gone from queries apparently. All of our queries that used $orderby are also broken!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was an [intentional (and breaking) change](https://dev.office.com/blogs/update-to-filtering-and-sorting-rest-api) made to address a major issue with filtering. `$orderby` is still very much a thing.

To sum up from that link, if you use both `$orderby` and `$filter` in a request:

1. Any fields in `$orderby` MUST also be in `$filter`.
2. Order of fields in `$filter` matters:

   1. Fields that are also in `$orderby` MUST come first in the `$filter` and MUST be in the same order.
   2. Fields that are not in `$orderby` MUST come after the fields that are in `$orderby`.

So according to those guidelines, the problem with your request is that `flag/dueDateTime/dateTime` is not present in `$filter`.

Comment: Why in hell did they do that?
2 years later and it's still an issue.
Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Good blog with some solutions eg. what IF u want to sort by date https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/update-to-filtering-and-sorting-rest-api/

Comment: Spot on!!! Thanks @Jason Johnston