# Microsoft Graph Email API, can't get focused emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to fetch emails from my inbox and trying to filter only the emails under the "Focused" tab.

I'm issuing this request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=InferenceClassification eq 'Focused'
```

and I get irrelevant messages, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be getting irrelevant emails, by default with that request url, you would get the emails sorted in ascending order by date of receipt, if you're looking for latest focused emails, try this request url

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$orderby=InferenceClassification, createdDateTime DESC&filter=InferenceClassification eq 'Focused'
```

If you're wondering why I issued the inferenceClassification under orderby, you may refer to below link for more clarity

[InefficientFilter error on Microsoft Graph requests which were previously working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662428/inefficientfilter-error-on-microsoft-graph-requests-which-were-previously-workin)