# Microsoft Graph, get emails filtered by sender and ordered by reception date: ODataError

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

```
var messagePage = await GraphHelper.UserClient.Me        
                .MailFolders["Inbox"]
                .Messages
                .GetAsync((config) =>
                {
                    config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "from", "isRead", "receivedDateTime", "subject" };

                    config.QueryParameters.Filter = "(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.sender@gmail.com'";
                    config.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "receivedDateTime DESC" };
                    
                });
```

I was expecting the above code to return the email from some.sender@gmail.com starting from the newest.
Instead I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
```

There are not further details.

#### What I tried

If I remove the filter (that is I comment the line `config.QueryParameters.Filter...` ) and I leave only the filter part, it works.
So it does if I remove the filter part and leave only the Orderby part.

So, they are right when taken alone, the problem is when they are issued together; this made me think of a problem in the syntax of HTTP query. I tried to add additional parentheses:

```
config.QueryParameters.Filter = "((from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.sender@gmail.com')";
```

No luck: same error.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you please catch the `ODataErrors`exception and post the message in `ODataErrors.Error.Message`?

Comment: The message seems not to be so informative: "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown" and so is the stack trace.

Comment: are you sure that you really cast a `ODataErrors` exception and that you access the message with e.g: `ex.Error.Message`?

Comment: I did this: catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Error.Message);
}. AND WHAT I GOT NOW IS: The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation.

Comment: This seems to lead to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662428/inefficientfilter-error-on-microsoft-graph-requests-which-were-previously-workin

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird behavior of the endpoint when using `$orderBy`. It's described in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#using-filter-and-orderby-in-the-same-query).

To fix the error, add `receivedDateTime` also to `$filter`. It must be the first filter condition.

```
var messagePage = await GraphHelper.UserClient.Me        
    .MailFolders["Inbox"]
    .Messages
    .GetAsync((config) =>
    {
        config.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "from", "isRead", "receivedDateTime", "subject" };
        config.QueryParameters.Filter = $"receivedDateTime le {DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} and (from/emailAddress/address) eq 'some.sender@gmail.com'";
        config.QueryParameters.Orderby = new[] { "receivedDateTime DESC" };
    });
```